# Masking a password argument in a console application

Tags: c#, passwords, command-line-arguments

I need to write a console application in C# which takes a username and password as input parameters.

Example: `mytool.exe --username foo --password bar`

Doing this is easy but of course the password would be visible on the screen as soon as the user types it. Security issue.

Is there any possibility to handle this in a more secure way? The following however is not an option:

```
C:\>mytool.exe
Please enter username:
Please enter password:
```

The application shall support being called without user interaction, e.g. being run by a cronjob on a regular basis.

Comment: Use your second option, and pipe the password from the cron job.

Comment: I guess it depends on how secure it needs to be. If you want some semblence of security, then you should be using `CredUICmdLinePromptForCredentials` http://joshpoley.blogspot.com/2011/10/securing-chickens-and-eggs.html

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate SLaks' comment:

Get the password from stdin (Standard Input).  In your cron job, use input redirection to pass in the password, e.g.

> MyConsoleProgram.exe < C:\SomeSecureFolder\Password.txt

The approach presented by @Ahmed will work well for cases where the program is used interactively from the command prompt.

Your program must run in a security context that allows access to Password.txt, but access the file should otherwise be restricted only to accounts that have a legitimate need to access it.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this? This will mask the password being entered:

```
if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace && key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
{
   pass += key.KeyChar;
   Console.Write("*");
}
else
{
   if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && pass.Length > 0)
   {
      pass = pass.Substring(0, (pass.Length - 1));
      Console.Write("\b \b");
   }
}
```

or even this....

```
            int chr=0;
            string pass="";
            const int ENTER = 13;
            do
            {
                chr = Console.Read();
                Console.Write ('*');
                pass += (char)chr;
            }
            while (chr!=ENTER);
```